qiskit transpile taking forever to run while CPU usage near zero
I am using the following code to use IBM's quantum computer. My understanding is that it is required before circuits are passed to the real quantum computers as certain operations and instructions need to be translated for the hardware.
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)


transpiled = pm.run(circuits)

However, this stage is taking forever to complete. Granted, I have a list of circuits (about 100 but all of them very simple and shallow) But I noticed my CPU usage is constantly at less than 5%. Is the transpilation stage run locally or on the cloud? Is there any way to expedite this process?
